# Multiple language items in search results

Tags: multilingual, azure-search

We have couple of sites configured under one Sitecore instance  for different languages, for example one for "Australia(en-AU)" and one for "Korea(KR)"

We are using Azure search and observing when we are performing site search the results are doubled for Australia site(all contents in Sitecore have two versions- "en" and "en-AU") i.e getting results from "en" version and "en-AU" version both. 
This seems to be working fine for other language i.e Korea as an example.

Search expresssion has language code added to it as filter :

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Parsing.IHasNativeQuery.Query = {Search
expression: &search=language_1:(en\-AU)&$filter=(all_templates/any(t:t
eq 'cedd694630184d5ga5453e3214985678')) and latestversion_1}
```

Are we missing anything here? please suggest.

Sitecore version: **Sitecore 8.2 update 4**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your content search code? Maybe using `context.GetQueryable<YourSearchContentItemType>(new CultureExecutionContext(Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo))` would help?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug for Sitecore 9. I assume it will also be present in your version.

Check here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/125044 The bug number in v9 is 171546.

> When Azure Search performs a search query that contains a hyphen for
>   items that are filtered by language, it returns the item for all
>   languages. (171546)

Contact Sitecore Support and you should be able to get a patch for it.

Comment: Thanks @Gatogordo - i requested patch for this from support which resolved my issue.